# custom aggregation with spring mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to do an aggregation query that combines documents from 2 collections like this:

```
db.clientData.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        id: {
            $in: db.clients.distinct("_id",
            {
                "tag": "qa"
            })
        }
    }
},
    $group: {
        _id: "$computerId",
        total_usage: {
            $sum: "$workingTime"
        }
    }
}]);
```

This is working fine when I run it from mongo shell, but I am having trouble running it from spring mongo.

I know how to create custom queries using 'BasicDBObject' but I don't know how to do that with "db.clients.distinct(".

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example :

```
basicDBObject.put("tarih",
                    new BasicDBObject("$gte", begisRequest.getBaslamaZamani())
                            .append("$lte", begisRequest.getSonaErmeZamani()));

isimler = mongoTemplate.getCollection("kesmePersonelDto").distinct(
                    "adi", basicDBObject);
```